# How do you make a while loop in python that stops two variables with the same answer?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to make a 'who wants to be a millionaire' style program with random questions, random answers in random places (in Python). I'm struggling to form a while loop that repeats itself so that two variables are never the same.
My loop (that clearly doesn't work) is:

```
while rnd4 == rnd2:
    rnd4 = random.randint(1,3)
    break
```

In context of my current program:

```
if rnd2 == 1:
    position1 = answer      #the random question has already been printed and the     
                            #answer set                   
elif rnd2 == 2:
    position2 = answer
elif rnd2 == 3:
    position3 = answer

rnd3 = random.randint(1,4)


rnd4 = random.randint(1,3)


while rnd3 == rnd1:
    rnd3 = random.randint(1,4)     #these loops are meant to mean that the same 
    break                          #answer is never repeated twice + the same  
while rnd4 == rnd2:                #position is never overwritten
    rnd4 = random.randint(1,3)
    break
if rnd3 == 1:
    if rnd4 == 1:
        position1 = (no1[1])
    elif rnd4 == 2:
        position2 = (no1[1])
    elif rnd4 == 3:
        position3 = (no1[1])
```

... (code skipped)

```
print (position1)
print (position2)
print (position3)
```

Due to the random nature of the program it has been difficult to test but I'm expecting a format like:

```
q1

answer
()  #only two of the positions have had code written for them yet
random answer
```

Or a combination of the above. (basically one right answer and one wrong answer in different positions)
Ocassionally I get:

```
q1

answer
answer
()
```

or

```
q1

random answer
()
()
```

So this is obviously wrong with sometimes the same answer printed twice or the wrong answer overwriting the right one.

Apologies for such a long drawn out question with probably a very simple answer (how to fix the loop) but I know I'm not supposed to ask for code!!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: totally unclear to me. why that many variables variations ?

Answer (score 1):

In Your Example `break` statement in while loops seems to be unnecessary.

this `brake` ends loop even if numbers are equal.

As I understand main ussue is to generate `rnd1` ... `rnd4`

can You try `random.shuffle` for these purposes

```
a = range(1, 5)
random.shuffle(a)
rnd1, rnd2, rnd3, rnd4 = a
```

`random.shuffle`  shuffle the sequence x in place. so one can generate sequence with desired values and shuffle it

Comment: this should help You to generate 4 random number

Answer (score 1):

Delete those `break` statements and it should work.

Assume your two variables are equal. Then you enter the loop, and you create a new value for rnd4. The next step would be to check if the 2 variables are now different, if not, repeat. But before you get to the while clause again you break out of the loop. So effectively you run the loop body at most once.